# ReplayKit broadcast to Web

Tags: swift, replaykit

With regards to ReplayKit, can the receiver of an A/V stream be a web browser?

I’m trying to validate if it’s possible to broadcast an iOS screen and receive it on a web browser. What does this conceptually look like? So far, all examples seem to be apps (mainly games) that depend on a Broadcaster App such as Mobcrush that function as both the Broadcaster App and the receiving app.

Thanks all.